# Can I use ssh password auth with the git-shell?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, git, authentication

On an Archlinux machine I am trying to set up password based authentication for a user. The users login shell should be set to the git-shell as to not allow command execution in the case of the account being compromised.

My sshd_config has a rule for just this one git user which appears to work as I can login with the user when I set the login shell to bash.
When however, the shell is set to git-shell I can't login. I am unsure as to how the shell and the password authentication are actually related.
To be clear: I am not using ChallengeResponseAuthentication but Authentication.

When trying to log in while git-shell is enabled I get the following error on the user side:

```
myuser@myhosts's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

On the server side, when starting the sshd with the -d flag I get this:

```
debug1: user myuser matched 'User myuser' at line 135
debug1: PAM: initializing for "myuser"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to <homeip>
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for myuser: Authentication failure
Failed password for myuser from <homeip> port 57470 ssh2
```

A successful attempt with bash as the shell looks like this:

```
debug1: user myuser matched 'User myuser' at line 135
debug1: PAM: initializing for "myuser"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "<homeip>"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for myuser
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted password for myuser from <homeip> port 57499 ssh2
```

Any ideas as to why this happens and how I could fix it? The simple way would be to just set up a key for the machines I actually use but it irks me that I can't get this to work.

Edit, output with DEBUG3:

```
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
debug3: PAM: sshpam_passwd_conv called with 1 messages
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for myuser: Authentication failure
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 0
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13
Failed password for myuser from <homeip> port 52928 ssh2
debug3: mm_auth_password: user not authenticated [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
```

Comment: What do you see if you increase log level to `DEBUG3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this problem existed due to the git-shell not being present in `/etc/shells`. Since I changed the users shell with root (using `chsh` with a specified username) while a warning was displayed it was possible to change the shell to the git-shell in the first place.

I am not entirely sure why key-based login was still possible but everything works now!

Generally `/etc/shells` is just a list of the allowed login shells but apparently it is not checked against in every case.